# How do I create message chat bubbles on the iPhone programmatically (like in iPhone Messages)

Tags: iphone, sms, bubble-popup

I was wondering if there is a way to build those chat bubbles programmatically from iOS?  If not iOS' own, then are there any decent open source libraries that will let me do that?

Comment: Why did this get a vote down? This is perfectly valid question and it helped me...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some examples [here](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/acanichat) and [here](http://alexbarinov.github.com/UIBubbleTableView/). You may also want to look at the `resizableImageWithCapInsets` method of the [UIImage class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thank you so much.  I would have thought that iOS had some kind of a built-in api for this, but I guess, it's roll your own :)