# recreating iOS SMS/Facebook Messenger text bubble tail

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm working on a chat feature in an app and I was trying to go off the style of iOS's SMS and Facebook's Messenger app for the speech bubbles around the text. My question is how can I make those little tails that come off the bottom left/right (depending on if sending or receiving) of the bubble? I'm having a hard time finding info/tutorial for this

Comment: You can have images of the same color of the bubble and with Autolayout set to bottom (left or right as apply). 

Also you can use a view and using CAShapeLayer create a mask  with the shape of the Tail.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13436170/1611876) You could fine some resources that might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do a similar thing and used this and it worked great!: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController